# password_get_info: not returning the expected result

Tags: php, passwords

I am just trying password functions.

```
<?php
$output=crypt("shivaf", "$6$rounds=50000$ldfjgfdjglkdfjgkljfdlgj$");
print_r(password_get_info($output));

$output=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n";
print_r(password_get_info($output));
```

This has to output the details of the hashing function I have used but I got the different output

output

```
Array ( [algo] => 0 [algoName] => unknown [options] => Array ( ) ) Array ( [algo] => 0 [algoName] => unknown [options] => Array ( ) )
```

I am just learning don't know what I have done wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password_get_info` works with passwords generated by `password_hash`.

Nothing you can do for `crypt` in the first example.

In second example you add `"\n"` to the hash, which makes it invalid. This works:

```
$output=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
print_r(password_get_info($output));
```

As a side note, you probably want to use single quotes for `crypt` example.

Comment: actually they password created with crypt is compatible with password_hash that's why tried it.

Comment: No, it is other way round. Hashes generated by `password_hash` are compatible with `crypt`. E.g. to show `bcrypt` and `cost = 10` in output of `password_get_info`, you can use `crypt` with salt like `$2y$10$some20charactersormore$` where `2y` stands for `bcrypt` and `10` represents cost. Disclaimer: even tho you **can**, you should not. Please use `password_hash` unless you have strong reasons to use bare `crypt`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the use of double quotes around this string `"$6$rounds=50000$ldfjgfdjglkdfjgkljfdlgj$"`

When you use double quotes PHP is trying to expand `$rounds=` as it it was a variable.

So just use single quotes instead. In fact unless you KNOW you want to expand a `$variable` you should always use single quotes to avoid such accidents.

```
<?php
$output=crypt("shivaf", '$6$rounds=50000$ldfjgfdjglkdfjgkljfdlgj$');
print_r(password_get_info($output));

$output=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
print_r(password_get_info($output));
```

Which would generate

```
 Array
(
    [algo] => 0
    [algoName] => unknown
    [options] => Array
        (
        )

)
Array
(
    [algo] => 1
    [algoName] => bcrypt
    [options] => Array
        (
            [cost] => 10
        )

)
```

But of course this just goes to prove that what Alex has said is almost true, which is that

> When passed in a valid hash created by an algorithm **supported by** password_hash(), this function will return an array of information about that hash.

Which are of course only these currently

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).
>
> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash. This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$" identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE on failure.

Comment: It must be single quotes, not backticks. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php